# Can "some" be followed by either a singular or a plural noun?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, determiners

The word *some* refers to an unspecified number or amount of an object. Are *some difficulty* and *some difficulties* both grammatical? If so, do they mean the same thing or two different things?

Answer (score 3):

Both are grammatical. They are used in different circumstances.

*Some difficulty* is a reference to an unquantifiable problem.

> *He had some difficulty in learning to drive.*

In contrast, *some difficulties* is a reference to a number of problems that are being aggregated.

> *He has had some difficulties lately, with the death of his mother, the loss of his job and the cancellation of his favorite television show.*